# Self referential join with Entity Framework Core and .net core 3.1

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am trying to create a self-referential join in EF Core, and have found several tutorials, but I keep getting the following error:

System.Text.Json.JsonException: A possible object cycle was detected which is not supported. This can either be due to a cycle or if the object depth is larger than the maximum allowed depth of 32.

My model looks like (showing only parts of interest:

```
   [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int SettingCollectionId { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }

    public ICollection<SettingValue> SettingValues { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SettingCollection> SubCollections { get; set; }
    public virtual SettingCollection ParentCollection { get; set; }
```

The context has this:

```
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<SettingCollection>()
            .HasMany<SettingValue>(sc => sc.SettingValues);
        modelBuilder.Entity<SettingCollection>()
            .HasMany(sc => sc.SubCollections)
            .WithOne(sc => sc.ParentCollection)
            .HasForeignKey(sc => sc.ParentId);
    }
```

In the controller, I need to pull the SettingValues(this works), but I also need to pull the SubCollections. I am getting this like so:

```
                var resultList =  await _context.SettingCollections
                .Where(sc => sc.ParentCollection == null)    
                .Where(sc => identifiers.Contains(sc.Identifier))
                .Include(sc => sc.SubCollections)
                .Include(sc => sc.SettingValues).OrderBy(sc => sc.Priority)
                .ToListAsync();
```

The line:

```
.Include(sc => sc.SubCollections)
```

causes this error to be thrown:

```
System.Text.Json.JsonException: A possible object cycle was detected which is not supported. This can either be due to a cycle or if the object depth is larger than the maximum allowed depth of 32.
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Please include all (3?) involved model classes with their relevant properties and relations. As far as I can see, `SettingValue` and `Identifier` are missing.

Comment: Does anything change when you replace `.Where(sc => sc.ParentCollection == null)` with `.Where(sc => sc.ParentId == null)`? Probably not, but I'd opt for the foreign key property instead of the navigation property.

Comment: @grek40 i tried it with `.Where(sc => sc.ParentId == null)` but got the same results. thanks!

Comment: @grek40 `SettingValue` is just a "has many" relationship that works fine. `Identifier` is just a string property. Thanks!

Comment: Since it works fine, I assume you get the same error when you remove the `.Where(sc => identifiers.Contains(sc.Identifier))` and the  `.Include(sc => sc.SettingValues)` from your query and only keep the problematic include?

Comment: @grek40 if i remove `.Where(sc => sc.ParentCollection == null)` , it works fine, other than i don't get subollections back..

Comment: I mean, what if you **only keep** the parent collection condition and the sub collection include and **remove everything else**? Does it still work then? If so: please remove those things from your question code that are not related to the problem

Answer (score 0):

try using Newtonsoft.Json in your project, in startup.cs:

```
services.AddMvc()
     .AddNewtonsoftJson(
          options => {
           options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore; 
      });
// if not using .AddMvc use these instead 
//services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(...);
//services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson(...);
//services.AddRazorPages().AddNewtonsoftJson(...);
```